# Unable to download image every 5 seconds

Tags: javascript, image, download, setinterval

I'm using the below script to check for internet connection by downloading the image test.png. The issue I'm having is that it will only download the image once. This means, if there was internet connection when the page was first loaded it will display "Online" - however, if I disconnect the network cable, it won't say "Offline", as it should.

Basically, once downloaded, the `readyState` will always be '`complete`' - However, I would like to perform the test again and again.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
setInterval('checkimage()', 1000);

function checkimage() {
    var imgTmp = new Image();
    imgTmp.src = 'test.png';
    if (imgTmp.readyState == 'complete') {
        document.getElementById('div1').innerHTML = "<font size=15 face=ariel color=green>Online</font>";
    } else {
        document.getElementById('div1').innerHTML = "<font size=15 face=ariel color=red>Offline</font>";
    }
}
</script>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It should be `setInterval('checkimage', 1000);` without parenthesis

Comment: @asifsid88 No, you're wrong. Either as string with paranthesis (the bad and wrong way) `setInterval("checkimage()", 1000)` or the function itself without paranthesis and quotes `setInterval(checkimage, 1000)` (the right way)

Comment: @Andreas ooops!! my bad. I missed the quotes too. TRUE! even the quotes shouldn't be there as we just pass the pointer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your solution is, that you're checking the readyState immediately after setting the source. Use the `load` and `error` events instead.

```
function checkimage() {
    var imgTmp = new Image();
    imgTmp.onload = function() {
        printState("Online");
    };
    imgTmp.onerror = function() {
        printState("Offline");
    };
    imgTmp.src = "test.png?_=" + (+new Date());
}

function printState(state) {
    document.getElementById("div1").innerHTML = "<span style=\"font-size:15;font-face:'Arial'; color:green\">" + state + "</span>";
    setTimeout(checkimage, 5000);
}
```

And don't use strings as first parameter for `setTimeout` and `setInterval`

Answer (score 2):

I'm doubtful about the whole solution but if you want to force a download, that is avoid the cache, you may replace

```
imgTmp.src = 'test.png';
```

with

```
imgTmp.src = 'test.png?t='+(new Date().getTime());
```

Comment: I tried your solution. It will always say offline - because file "test.png?t='+(new Date().getTime());" doesn't exist.

Comment: Hu ? What's your server ? Isn't it able to fetch a file when there are paremeters ?

Comment: @EliUnger: `?` introduces a query string. It's not part of the filename on disk.

Comment: I've reread your first comment : you have a typo (quotes). Copy my code.